# How to deal with awkward pronoun repetition?

Tags: style, creative-writing

Example from my writing:

> Aru smiled back at him and at his thought. “I think there’s no need to
>   find him.” So what if Ichi wasn't a prime number? Their hearts
>   combined would produce a **one, one** that might make her
>   infinitely happy.
>
> Two.

What to do in cases where you have awkward pronoun repetition?

Comment: I don't think this question is off topic, as it does not ask for help rephrasing the example passage, but explicitly asks what to do "in cases *like these*" (my emphasis). The example is given to illustrate the problem and there is no appeal to help rephrase it. So please find a better reason to close this question, if you must, but I would leave it open as perfectly within site rules.

Comment: I think it's borderline, but it is a common situation. "the the" is an analogous situation.

Comment: What does the second paragraph mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with the repetition in this case. It emphasizes the important information in a pleasant manner.

If you want to avoid repetition of words, what you can do is

## rephrase

your sentence(s). How to rephrase will depend on the given situation, and asking for and giving help rephrasing passages is off topic on this site.