# How can I rephrase that that?

Tags: academic-writing

I know its okay to leave it as "that that's why" but it sounds awkward. This is the sentence "It is very possible that since the armadillidium are not exposed to processed alcohol based scents daily that that is why they showed the preference the did"

Comment: "It is very possible that the armadillidium showed the preference they did because they are not exposed to processed alcohol based scents daily."

Comment: It is very possible that their preference for armalillidium arose from its not having been exposed to processed alcohol based scents on a daily basis.

Comment: Hi mimi, and welcome to Writers. Requests to rephrase a single sentence are off-topic for us, but they may be acceptable on English SE if phrased correctly. I've asked the mods if they can migrate.

Comment: @LaurenIpsum I believe this question can easily be rephrased to focus on any instance of `that that`. No need to move it, as it is about writing, and not so much the proper use of English (given that `that that` is proper). See my answer below.

Comment: Please consider rephrasing as has been suggested, we'd be happy to consider reopening.

Comment: Related, recent question: [How to deal with awkward pronoun repetition?](http://writers.stackexchange.com/q/26180/26)

Answer (score 1):

This is a common problem I face as well. Sometimes there's nothing you can do about it, and have to leave two `that`'s together. But usually, you can fix it by using the following rule:

### Replace a 'that' with what it refers to.

In any sentence with two `that`'s, at least one of them is acting in place of another word or phrase. For example, let's break down your sentence. The first `that` is not referring to another word, but the second one is. It's referring to the `armadillidium are not exposed to processed alcohol based scents daily` part. You could just repeat that phrase in place of the `that`, but that would sound even more awkward. So what you can do is use a different word to refer to the phrase.

> It is very possible that since the armadillidium are not exposed to processed alcohol based scents daily that **because of this** they showed the preference they did.

Another example would be in my previous paragraph. I write:

> You could just repeat that phrase in place of the `that`, but that would sound even more awkward.

I could replace the second that with what it refers to: repetition.

> You could just repeat that phrase in place of the `that`, but **doing so** would sound even more awkward.

It takes some practice, and you can't do this to every `that` you will encounter. You can do it to most though, and your writing will benefit for it.

Good luck!

---

*Aside:* Just correcting grammar as I go: Don't forget the period at the end of the sentence, and I believe you want the second to last word to be `they`, not `the`. Also the tenses in your sentence shift. It starts out in present, and ends up in past. You might want to tweak it to be one or the other.